# How to show close icon once the file upload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What I am doing, Once any user uploads the file then I have to enable the cross sign on the file.

I tried using javascript but it's not working.  I have more than 8-10 file types.

The below is the screenshot of the file.

[image]

The below is the screenshot after uploading the file.

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  // const max_fields = 5;
  const $wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap .upload_file");
  $wrapper.on('change', '.fileupload', function() {
    imagesPreview(this);
  });

  // Multiple images preview in browser
  const imagesPreview = function(input) {
    const placeToInsertImagePreview = $(input).parent().find('div.gallery');

    if (input.files) {
      var filesAmount = input.files.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
        var src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[i]);
        $('<img>').attr('src', src).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
      }
    }
  };
});

var fileInput = document.getElementsByClassName('fileupload');
fileInput.onchange = function() {
  var input = this.files[0];
  if (input) {
    //alert("uploaded");
    $('.remove_field').show();
  }
};
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.upload_file {
  border: 3px dashed #042954;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  height: 120px;
}

.upload_file input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove_field {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.upload_file img {
  width: 100px;
}

.customfileWrap {
  position: relative;
}

.width30 {
  width: 300px;
}

.remove_field img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="myprofile" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myprofile">
  <div class="width30 input_fields_wrap">
    <div class="upload_file">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="1" class="close_img remove_field" style="display: none;"><img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/navigation/close_black_256x256.png"></a>
      <input type="file" name="file1" class="fileupload">
      <span class="excel_upload_icon"></span>
      <span class="upload_text"> Click here to upload file </span>
      <img id="previewimg1" src="#" alt="" class="previewimg" />
      <div class="gallery"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="width30 input_fields_wrap">

    <div class="upload_file">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="2" class="close_img remove_field" style="display: none;"><img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/navigation/close_black_256x256.png"></a>
      <input type="file" name="file2" class="fileupload">
      <span class="excel_upload_icon"></span>
      <span class="upload_text"> Click here to upload file </span>
      <img id="previewimg2" src="#" alt="" class="previewimg" />
      <div class="gallery"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you want to show a preview of the file, use `src = URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using the FileReader

Comment: @Endless, Can you help me with an example? because I got this answer from google.

Comment: updated your code example to use object urls instead

Comment: @Endless, Let me check. Give me sometime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some css and made a object inside your fileuploader:

CSS:

```
.upload_file .cross {
  position:absolute;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:red;
  top:-10px;
  right:-10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:none;
}

.upload_file.haveFile .cross{
  display:block;
}
```

Html added:

```
<div class="cross">X</div>
```

Last we will add a class to the uploader so it knows it has an element.

```
placeToInsertImagePreview.closest(".upload_file").addClass("haveFile")
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  // const max_fields = 5;
  const $wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap .upload_file");
  $wrapper.on('change', '.fileupload', function() {
    imagesPreview(this);
  });

  // Multiple images preview in browser
  const imagesPreview = function(input) {
    const placeToInsertImagePreview = $(input).parent().find('div.gallery');

    if (input.files) {
      var filesAmount = input.files.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
        var src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[i]);
        $('<img>').attr('src', src).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
        placeToInsertImagePreview.closest(".upload_file").addClass("haveFile");
      }
    }
  };
});

var fileInput = document.getElementsByClassName('fileupload');
fileInput.onchange = function() {
  var input = this.files[0];
  if (input) {
    //alert("uploaded");
    $('.remove_field').show();
  }
};
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.upload_file {
  border: 3px dashed #042954;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  height: 120px;
}

.upload_file .cross {
  position:absolute;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:red;
  top:-10px;
  right:-10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:none;
}

.upload_file.haveFile .cross{
  display:block;
}

.upload_file input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove_field {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.upload_file img {
  width: 100px;
}

.customfileWrap {
  position: relative;
}

.width30 {
  width: 300px;
}

.remove_field img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="myprofile" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myprofile">
  <div class="width30 input_fields_wrap">
    <div class="upload_file">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="1" class="close_img remove_field" style="display: none;"><img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/navigation/close_black_256x256.png"></a>
      <input type="file" name="file1" class="fileupload">
      <span class="excel_upload_icon"></span>
      <span class="upload_text"> Click here to upload file </span>
      <img id="previewimg1" src="#" alt="" class="previewimg" />
      <div class="gallery"></div>
      <div class="cross">X</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="width30 input_fields_wrap">

    <div class="upload_file">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="2" class="close_img remove_field" style="display: none;"><img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/navigation/close_black_256x256.png"></a>
      <input type="file" name="file2" class="fileupload">
      <span class="excel_upload_icon"></span>
      <span class="upload_text"> Click here to upload file </span>
      <img id="previewimg2" src="#" alt="" class="previewimg" />
      <div class="gallery"></div>
      <div class="cross">X</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Give me sometime to check

Comment: Yes, it's working. thank you so much for the help